# Compiling with gcc and terminal

Tags: c, gcc, terminal

I am attempting to compile C files from http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000081.php that I literally copy and pasted, so I do not believe there is any type of syntax error, yet I keep getting errors. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I'm using a text editor called TextWrangler to save my write and save my files. I have Xcode downloaded along with its terminal tools so that shouldn't be an issue either.

Here are the errors:

```
testc4.c:4: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’ token
song.c:5: error: function definition declared ‘typedef’
song.c:5: error: return type is an incomplete type
song.c: In function ‘make_song’:
song.c:6: error: ‘Song’ undeclared (first use in this function)
song.c:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
song.c:6: error: for each function it appears in.)
song.c:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘newSong’
song.c:8: error: ‘newSong’ undeclared (first use in this function)
song.c:12: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
song.c: At top level:
song.c:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘theSong’
```

Here is the command I'm using to compile my program:

```
gcc testc4.c song.c -o testc4
```

If needed I can post the files but they are copied right from the tutorial. I named my test file testc4.c instead of whatever it wanted.

Edit: (I figured you'd need to code)

testc4.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "song.h"

main ()
{
  Song firstSong  = make_song (210, 2004);
  Song secondSong = make_song (256, 1992);

  Song thirdSong  = { 223, 1997 };
  display_song ( thirdSong );

  Song fourthSong = { 199, 2003 };
}
```

song.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "song.h"

Song make_song (int seconds, int year)
{
  Song newSong;

  newSong.lengthInSeconds = seconds;
  newSong.yearRecorded    = year;
  display_song (newSong);

  return newSong;
}

void display_song (Song theSong)
{
  printf ("the song is %i seconds long ", theSong.lengthInSeconds);
  printf ("and was made in %i\n", theSong.yearRecorded);
}
```

song.h file

```
typedef struct {
  int lengthInSeconds;
  int yearRecorded;
} Song;

Song  make_song    (int seconds, int year);
void  display_song (Song theSong);
```

These are straight copied from the site. I typed them out first but when it didn't work I copy and pasted them.

Comment: You might want to paste what you're compiling. Something's clearly wrong.

Comment: We need to see at least lines 1-15 of `song.c`, and also any header that you wrote and is included in those lines.  Please see how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  For example, we don't need comments if the code you provide reproduces the error messages.

Comment: Double check that you are using LF as your newline separator. This may otherwise give you problems. I tried it and this command line compiles out of the box on my OS X `gcc 4.2.1`

Comment: Compile with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g` and improve the code till you get no warnings!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just have to change:

`main ()`

to

`void main ()`

Comment: main should return int.

Comment: This is correct. But this main returns nothing. This is the least modifications that may avoid compilation error.